# In PHP MySQL how to sum or not sum multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, php, sum

I have three tables this is my codes:

```
<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Mark1</th>
        <th>Mark2</th>
        <th>Mark3</th>
        <th>Sum Marks</th>
        </tr>

<?php
    $query2 = "SELECT  students_info.s_name, subjects.subject, marks.*
            FROM  subjects
            RIGHT JOIN  (students_info
            RIGHT JOIN  marks  ON students_info.s_id = marks.s_id
                )  ON subjects.sub_id = marks.sub_id
            WHERE  students_info.s_id = '".$s_id."'";

    $result2=mysqli_query($link,$query2) OR die(mysqli_error($link));   

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
        {
 ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['subject'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['n1'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['n2'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['n3'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['n1']+$row['n2']+$row['n3'];?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
        }
?>
        </table>
 <?php
}
?>
```

Output my codes:

[image]

I want when each mark form(mark1,mark2,mark3) for every subject less than 49 the sum operation not work in the cell sum marks appear empty value or empty cell,
Please review my code and give me a help, to do work this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could add them up in SQL by reverting to 0 for NULL columns like:

```
SELECT students_info.s_name, subjects.subject, marks.*, 
       COALESCE(marks.n1, 0) + COALESCE(marks.n2, 0) +COALESCE(marks.n3, 0) as  sum_marks
FROM ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @danblack, i used your code but the same output appear, **i want to when each mark less than(<49) the cell Sum Marks must be empty for this row**

Comment: I don't quite get the criteria however use: [IF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)( expr < 49, 0, val).

Comment: I used this criteria, but this way save only makr3 :( .

Comment: `IF( marks.n1 < 49 AND marks.n2 < 49 AND marks.n3 < 49, NULL, COALESCE(marks.n1, 0) + COALESCE(marks.n2, 0) +COALESCE(marks.n3, 0))`

Comment: Thanks @danblack, that's worked for me, but if the name subjects on the header  name students on the left and marks on the center how this code work for sum?

Comment: The sum depends on the rows retrieved. It doesn't matter what adjacent fields are in the `SELECT` output. If you `GROUP BY student.name, subject` the result is equally as valid. If that doesn't match the question you think you asked, I couldn't follow your question.